rss feed missing site icon and tagline - no issues found in validator - wordpress site
I have a wordpress.org website I'm using to host a webcomic and as I'm updating again I'm keen to ensure my rss feed is up to professional standard to make sure nobody misses any updates. Wordpress generates rss feeds for its websites automatically (mine is here: https://stringcomic.co.uk/comic/feed/) but my site icon and tagline (i.e. description) don't show up, which makes it look rather moribund next to all the other comics in my feed.
I cannot find any issues with the feed and everything else (thumbnails, featured images etc.) show up in the feeder absolutely fine, so I'm a bit stumped as to what's causing the blockage.
-
My site identity options are fully filled in and I can see my site icon and tagline in all other browsers.
I installed (and uninstalled) a couple of plugins to enter a site icon manually but neither took, but these efforts directed me to an rss validator (http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A//stringcomic.co.uk/comic/feed/) that confirmed it was valid and cautioned only "Use of unknown namespace: com-wordpress:feed-additions:1" and "content:encoded should not contain iframe tag".
As far as I've been able to research, "com-wordpress:feed-additions:1" is a consequence of some plugin or another entering its own id tags that should otherwise have no effect on the feed's appearance. Likewise, the presence of iframes is irrelevant, some external sites were embedded but these shouldn't affect the feed. A further investigation of the code shows that the site icon and description are both present and should be showing up:
<channel>
<title>String</title>
<atom:link href="https://stringcomic.co.uk/comic/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
<link>https://stringcomic.co.uk/comic/</link>
<description>An Urban Fantasy Webcomic</description>
<lastBuildDate>Sat, 20 Apr 2024 15:12:38 +0000</lastBuildDate>
<language>en-US</language>
<sy:updatePeriod>
hourly </sy:updatePeriod>
<sy:updateFrequency>
1 </sy:updateFrequency>
<generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=6.5.2</generator>
 
<image>
<url>https://stringcomic.co.uk/comic/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/String_logo_thumbnail.gif</url>
<title>String</title>
<link>https://stringcomic.co.uk/comic/</link>
<width>32</width>
<height>32</height>
</image>
<site xmlns="com-wordpress:feed-additions:1">139604174</site>

The feed file which picks up the site icon, stringcomic.co.uk/public_html/comic/wp-includes/feed.php, is in its default state:
function rss2_site_icon() {
    $rss_title = get_wp_title_rss();
    if ( empty( $rss_title ) ) {
        $rss_title = get_bloginfo_rss( 'name' );
    }

    $url = get_site_icon_url( 32 );
    if ( $url ) {
        echo '
<image>
    <url>' . convert_chars( $url ) . '</url>
    <title>' . $rss_title . '</title>
    <link>' . get_bloginfo_rss( 'url' ) . '</link>
    <width>32</width>
    <height>32</height>
</image> ' . "\n";
    }
}

I'm also not sure where I should be looking to get the tagline entered ("description" in the php file's parlance). I would've thought Yoast SEO would have the title format covered but that doesn't appear to be the case.
Any insights into what I could be missing would be very helpful. This is an old site that's been macgyver'd from a bespoke ComicPress theme so I'm scared to touch half of it, but this is one case where everything on paper seems to be working fine so that not happening is a little mystifying.

Just as an update, I was able to determine that the feed was outputting an image with the incorrect size as I hadn't originally uploaded a site icon that was 512x512 pixels. With that done, the site icon url is now: https://stringcomic.co.uk/comic/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/cropped-String_logo_wordpress-32x32.png - unfortunately this doesn't seem to have done the trick. I compared the rss feed output to the output of another Wordpress-based webcomic that does have an icon and they're nearly identical, and yet still no icon.

Further updates! I recently divided my site into two domains - I spun out my portfolio site to rosshopkins.co.uk and consolidated my comic site into stringcomic.co.uk (so neither site is any longer located in a sub-directory). The rss feed for my portfolio site now shows my icon: https://rosshopkins.co.uk/feed/ - but the feed for my comic site still doesn't: https://stringcomic.co.uk/feed/ - They are both now single-site installs, both have identical infrastructure and feed outputs, and yet one displays an icon in an rss reader and one does not. I continue to be baffled and perplexed.

More updates! I've been doing a spot of gardening on my site, updating the theme and doing staging tests and the like, and throughout this process the site icon has intermittently appeared in some sections of my RSS reader and not others. I've surmised that the cache on the feeder's end takes a few hours to update, which makes identifying what exactly I did to unclog the tubes extremely difficult, as by the time the icon appears in a random part of the reader I've made a bunch of other tweaks to the website and a few hours later the icon vanishes again.

I'm not an expert, so proceed with caution (and site backups or, even better, a staging site):

Clear Caches: Start by clearing all caches—your website, browser, and any CDN caches. This could be the issue (don't need to back up for this one). After you've done this, check again.

Find Possible Conflicts: Switch to a default WordPress theme and then turn off all of your non-essential plugins. This can help you figure out if there’s a conflict messing with your feed. After you've done this, check again :)



Cheers! I've cleared the cache after every change but it doesn't seem to have had much effect. I have a sub-site with a default template (my portfolio site) which serves as a staging site and seems to be experiencing the same issue (and which also seems fine according to the validator: http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A//stringcomic.co.uk/comic/portfolio/feed/). I've tested every plugin I've installed with the exception of Comic Easel, which unfortunately I can't touch without risking messing up six years of content. But thanks for the tips, they've been super-useful!
